# Include parent and child in query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities with one to many relationship like this:

> Customer 1......* Booking

```
 public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    }


  public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; };

    }
```

If _context being DbContext, following two queries ended up in circular dependency.

```
_context.Customers.Include(x=> x.Bookings).ToList();
```

OR

```
_context.Bookings.Include(x=> x.Customer).ToList();
```

Question is how can we query these interdependent relationships if we have to include entity A in B's query and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForeignKey attribute defined in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ParentChild
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Booking
    {
        [Key]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BookingDate { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentChildDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        public ParentChildDbContext(String connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public String ConnectionString { get; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Booking> Booking { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new ParentChildDbContext("server=(local);database=ParentChild;integrated security=yes;");

            var data = dbContext.Customer.Include(p => p.Bookings).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Customer: {0}, Bookings: {1}", data.First().Name, data.First().Bookings.Count);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I've created a database for this test:

```
create database ParentChild
go

use ParentChild
go

create table Customer
(
    Id int not null identity(1, 1),
    Name varchar(50) not null
)

create table Booking
(
    Id int not null identity(1, 1),
    Title varchar(50) not null,
    BookingDate datetime not null,
    CustomerId int not null
)
go

insert into Customer values ('Parent')
go

insert into Booking values ('First booking', getdate(), 1)
go
```

Output result:

**Customer: Parent, Bookings: 1**

Comment: tried with virtual keyword, but doesn't make any difference to queries. Don't use fluent api as convention based approach works as per EF documentation. Have you got some examples of relational entities and how to query and include the relational entities in one query.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. Adding virtual and Foreign key attributes don't make any difference. Check this sample by EF core team.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Querying/Querying/RelatedData/Sample.cs
they haven't used virtual or attributes, but the conventions.

Comment: You use a different convention, you use a property id in Customer and Booking classes instead of CustomerId and BookingId, have you tried it ?

Comment: H. Hezl, still doesn't work. I have changed the attributes as you suggested, but that doesn't make any difference. BTW I have updated the question as Customer id in booking is nullable because while booking, customer can be null and can be added later on, so not sure if that is causing any grief.

Comment: I've created a test project, I updated my answer with full code and results, please check it and let me know if is useful

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to above problem in my case as I was using Asp.Net Core was to tell in MVC options to handle reference loops as follows:

```
 services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7154#issuecomment-263683260) with EF core team to answer if reference looping should be handled on consumer end or it should be handled by EF Core. Will update the answer once get a response.